# Nginx not loading Meteor packages : Getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, meteor, nginx, nodes, reverse-proxy

Here is what i am trying to accomplish..... i am trying to setup a reverse proxy server using nginx on my dev machine and host three meteor apps locally on diffrent local port. I want my nginx to redirect requests based on the virtual directory...something like localhost/App1 would redirect to localhost:3010 and localhost/App2 would to localhost:3011. These apps will need to use Meteor Identity micro service (third app) for authentication and the apps will need to use something like localhost/Iden to redirect unauthenticated users

As a first step i have this Setup:
I am trying to deploy app1 Meteor app on Nginx locally. I have build the app with "meteor build" and moved the content to Nginx/html where my root is. Once i browse the app through nginx port (localhost:81) I am not able to load any meteor packages but able to load the app files. The app itself is running on localhost:3000

Below is the error

[Error screenshot : Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qluRa.png)

I am able to browse the resource files that i created, such as todo.js, individually

> localhost:81/app/template.todo1.js?979b20f66caf126704c250fbd29ce253c6cb490e

but i am NOT able to browse to meteor packages files

> localhost:81/packages/global-imports.js?af67437fd606dadafb22ec5e8bfc6ca8314a60ad

as it returns 404

Below is my config from nginx

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server {
    listen       0.0.0.0:81;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

      location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{60}\.(css|js)$" {
        root /app1/bundle/programs/server;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
      }

      location ~ "^/packages" {
        root /app1/bundle/programs/server;
        access_log off;
      }

     location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
       root /app1/bundle/programs/server;
       access_log off;
       expires max;
     }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }
    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3010;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    } 

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}

}
```

Any help appreciated as i am struggling with this issue since yesterday

Comment: you misunderstood something. You should move *anything* into your nginx root. Perhaps you are trying to use nginx as a proxy (which is a common use), but even that is not necessary. Please explain in your question what you are trying to accomplish (right now it's just describing what you did and what doesn't work, but not why you did that and what the ultimate goal is).

Comment: Here is what i am trying to accomplish..... i am trying to setup a reverse proxy server using nginx on my dev machine and host three meteor apps locally on diffrent local port. I want my nginx to redirect requests based on the virtual directory...something like localhost/App1 would redirect to localhost:3010 and localhost/App2 would to localhost:3011. These apps will need to use Meteor Identity micro service (third app) for authentication and the apps will need to use something like localhost/Iden to redirect unauthenticated users...Hope this is clear

Comment: If a reverse proxy is all you want, then I would recommend looking at redbird (https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird). Creating a reverse proxy with that is *much* simpler than with nginx. I use it all the time in exactly the way you describe (one host, multiple meteor projects), and it's super easy to set up.

Comment: wow...Thanks....Just what i need...

Comment: @Christian Fritz : Can you point me to any working example, if there exists one.

Comment: the main example on the github page I linked to already has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a reverse proxy then I recommend using [redbird](https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird):

```
npm install redbird
```

And then, for instance, if you have two meteor apps running locally on ports 3000 and 4000:

proxy.js:

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80});
proxy.register("myfirstapp.com", "http://localhost:3000");
proxy.register("mysecondapp.com", "http://localhost:4000");
```

and then run:

```
sudo node proxy.js
```

Note that it doesn't matter whether the meteor apps are running from a bundle or still using `meteor`. But of course the former is advisable for production.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Quick question. Can i register something like this var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 3010}); proxy.register("127.0.0.1";, "127.0.0.1:3000");

Comment: the following config does not work. var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80});
proxy.register("example.com/aaa", "http://127.0.0.1:3010");
proxy.register("example.com/bbb", "http://127.0.0.1:3000"); Were you able to figure this one? When i access the URL with this config, i get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" with Not found in every resource file...while subdomain.domain.com setup works...its only when you have paths after domain i see this problem..

Comment: no, I never tried that. I suspect that meteor doesn't like the mismatch of url and path that that introduces.